# Has there been a recent update to chromes webgl implementation?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webgl

I am developing a website which can be found [here](http://www.berrybox.co.uk/lbm/test/web_tunnel.htm).

In a nutshell this is a fluid dynamics solver executing in webgl fragment shaders. The result is mapped to a textured quad and rendered on the canvas.

While doing some development work this weekend, I noticed that the Low and Medium resolution versions of the page are no longer working on Chrome (see the links in top right corner). However, if you open the page in Firefox everything works as expected. Be warned, this page is not expected to work on mac unless you've enabled webgl, it doesnt work in IE, and I havent tested it with opera.

A few other odd symptoms:

- The mapping of mouse position to canvas position is now wrong in chrome unless the window is fullscreen.
- The low and medium quality version appear to show only a tiny section of the low right corner of the texture.

  - To observe this in low/medium click the Analyze tab, and quickly change the velocity slider between low and high. Try this out in high mode to see the difference.
- Last weekend the framerate in chrome was 60fps on my machine, its now 30fps even in high quality. Firefox gets a stead 60fps

The only real difference between the low, medium and high implementations is the texture resolution, which is 256x32, 512x64, 1024x128 respectively.

Can anyone shed some light on what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but based on the simulation (and the corruption artifacts I'm seeing) it seems like you may be using floating point textures to store/render the simulation state. There was a semi-recent change in Chrome that fixed a bug in how filtered floating point textures were exposed and required some code changes. You can read about it here:

[IMPORTANT: Your WebGL floating point texture usage needs to be fixed!!!!](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/public-mailing-list/archives/1305/msg00022.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm using unsigned byte textures.